# Cocoapod issues with swift/objc project and testting target

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xctest, cedar-bdd

I'm working with a mostly OBJc project,Tests are done with Cedar. I've started including swift and am having issues with cocoapod frameworks in my test target

Cocoapods version is 0.39.0 (upgrading to the beta gave me more issues so sticking with stable for now)
My podfile looks like this:

```
def test_pods
    pod 'Cedar'
    pod 'PivotalCoreKit/Development'
end

def app_pods
    pod 'PivotalCoreKit'
    pod 'JSONWebToken'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end


target 'App' do
    use_frameworks!
    app_pods
end

target 'AppTests' do
    use_frameworks!
    test_pods
end
```

The issue I'm having right now is when building for tests, it gives me "Can't find symbol" errors for all the pods in the main app target.

What I've done:

- Added pods to both targets(produces error saying class exists twice)
- Tried setting use frameworks only for app target
- link_with, produces the same result as if adding them to both targets

I have a full swift app, that works just fine when setting the test pods to only the test target, so I'm assuming that because this is a hybrid code base, I'm seeing some issues.